# Multiprocessing в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing, pool

**Выдаёт ошибку**

```
RuntimeError: 
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Код:

```
ip_list = []

def testIP(IP):
    try:
        if requests.get("https://avito.ru/", proxies=IP).status_code == 200:
            ip_list.append(IP)
    except:
        return None

def pool(listIP):
    with Pool(20) as p:
        data = p.map(testIP, listIP)
   return data
```

**Где `listIP` это список прокси.**

Comment: где вы pool вызываете?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У меня была похожая проблема, решилась путем добавления конструкции:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

перед  исполняемым кодом. Попробуйте вот в таком стиле, и кстати Pool поддерживает контекстный менеджер with:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func( x ):
    return x + 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vals = [1, 2, 3]
    with Pool(10) as pool:
        res = pool.map(func, vals)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Если Вас устроил ответ примите его, нажав галочку.